# java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to update values using JDBC and I continue to get the same error for different tables and with different schemas.

Let's say that I have a table like this

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| field1         | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| field2         | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

then, I try to add a row:

```
String Text1 = text1;
String Text2 = text2;
String Query_String = "INSERT INTO tablename(field1,field2) VALUES ('"+Text1+","+Text2+"')";
Query_Statement.executeUpdate(Query_String);
```

the number of columns is the same, and also in the text there are not other commas, but I continue to get the error "java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

I'm sure it's something simple, probably on the syntax since I managed to make it to work with a single column...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is something wrong with:

```
String Query_String = "INSERT INTO tablename(field1,field2) VALUES ('"+Text1+","+Text2+"')";
```

You've missed some quotes between Text1 and Text2:

```
String Query_String = "INSERT INTO tablename(field1,field2) VALUES ('"+Text1+"','"+Text2+"')";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String Query_String = "INSERT INTO tablename(field1,field2) VALUES ("'"+Text1+"' , '"+Text2+"');";
```

It should like this note `'` this

[PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/preparedstatement.html) would be better choice.

Comment: +1 for suggesting prepared statement.

Answer (score 1):

you have got a mistake with your quotes...

the following will be executed: 
`INSERT INTO tablename(field1,field2) VALUES ('Text1,Text2');`

you have to write:
`String Query_String = "INSERT INTO tablename(field1,field2) 
VALUES ('"+Text1+"','"+Text2+"')"`